# Homebrew - different packages on different computers, same MacOS

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install `far2l` on two different computers, but the result is different. Screenshot from the first computer:

[image: Homebrew far2l installation]

Screenshot from the second:

[image]

In the first case it installs from `yurikoles/far2l`, on the second `https://github.com/elfmz/far2l`.

The second way is preferred, since it creates an icon in Applications. But for some unknown reason the first computer tries to pull the wrong one. Why?

Homebrew is 4.2.3 on both computers:

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 4.2.3
```

Comment: It's not the same operation between both pictures you provided. In the first one, `far2l` is not already installed on the computer (it tries to use https://github.com/elfmz/far2l/archive/refs/tags/v_2.5.2.tar.gz) but you already have it on the computer (in cache). However, on the second screenshot, the command **upgrades** `far2l`.

Comment: You may consider to clear your cache in the first computer and try again. - The cache is in : `/Users/elel/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
brew uninstall far2l
brew install homebrew/cask/far2l
```

Did the trick